# Python IndexError: list assignement index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am trying to print the RGB value of a picture at a specific coordinate `(cx=125/cy=200)` and the RGB values of 9 more pixels which are below this coordinate with a distance of 4 between each pixel.

Example of the Output:

```
(from left to right: X-coordinate,    Y-coordinate,    R,   G,    B)

125, 200, 50, 200, 30
125, 196, 55, 250, 31
125, 192, 52, 271, 34
125, 188, 50, 284, 24
125, 184, 53, 234, 45
125, 180, 58, 243, 40
125, 176, 50, 225, 33
125, 172, 53, 263, 38
125, 168, 70, 237, 35
125, 164, 56, 201, 37
```

Code as below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread('C:\colorbars.png')
template = cv2.resize(template,(640,480))
height, width, depth = template.shape

tempx = []
tempy = []
b = [255]
g = [255]
r = [255]
i = 0
cx = 125
cy = 200

while i  < 10:
    x = cx * (float(width)) / 640
    tempx.insert(i, x)
    y = (cy-4) * (float(width)) / 480
    tempy.insert(i, y)
    b[i], g[i], r[i] = template[tempy[i]][tempx[i]]
    print tempx[i],tempy[i],r[i],g[i],b[i]
    i += 1

    cv2.imshow('template', template)
```

I chose `R, G, B[255]` because their maximum value is 255, is this correct?

I am fairly new to Python so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Error traceback:

```
C:\Users\Patrick:>C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\test.py
125.0 261.333333333333 88 49 27
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\test.py", line 23, in <module>
b[i], g[i], r[i] = template[tempy[i]][tempx[i]]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your post!

Comment: Your `x` and `y` have the same values in every iteration. Also, why do you write `template[tempy[i]][tempx[i]]` instead of the much more readable `template[y][x]`?

Comment: @KlausD.
I added the traceback, hope it helps.

@user3760780
Good point! So if I add the variable `n`it should provide different outputs for `y` (`x` should remain the same) 
    
    `n = 0
    
    i  < 10:
    x = cx * (float(width)) / 640
    tempx.insert(i, x)
    y = (cy-4) * (float(width)) / 480
    tempy.insert(i, y)
    b[i], g[i], r[i] = template[tempy[i]][tempx[i]]
    print tempx[i],tempy[i],r[i],g[i],b[i]
    i += 1
    n -= 4`

Comment: @user3760780: I have changed my code multiple times, this is why it looks a bit messy... seems like I do not need the `tempx` and `tempy` anymore or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `r= [255]` it is creating a list of just one element.

When you are iterating over r ,g,b using i from 0 to 10, you are trying to access an index which does not exist.That's why you are getting `index out of range error`

If you want to create a list of more than one element with some initial value you can use

```
r = ([initial_value] * 255) # creates a list of 255 element
```

Comment: And what is the `initial value?`

Comment: Any value you would like to give.List is same as array in c.So r = [255] is just a list with one element as 255.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
Got it to work. Just used `r = ([10] * 255)` for `g` and `b` as well